# SPGridview Sorting issue with Modal control - Double postback

Tags: modal-dialog, spgridview, postback

I'm having a a issue related to Sharepoint/ASP.Net Postbacks.

Basically, what's happening is I have the following GridView on my page:

```
 <SharePoint:SPGridView 
    EnableViewState="false" runat="server" 
    ID="gvSettings" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    DataSourceID="MyObjectDataSource" 
    AllowGrouping="true" 
    GroupField="CategoryValue" 
    AllowGroupCollapse="true"
    AllowSorting="true" 
    AllowFiltering="true" 
    OnRowCommand="gvCurrentSettings_rowCommand"
     EnablePersistedSelection="true" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="true">
```

Everything in the gridview works as it should. The problem is to do with the Paging controls. My Gridview has a SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate which opens a Modal Popup when you click to Edit an Item. The popup works fine.

Ever since i've gone and implemented Sorting on the Gridview the following happens:

1. Clicking on a Column to sort by the column works fine.
2. Next, clicking on the Menu and selecting edit opens up a Modal Popup.
3. Clicking on a Save button inside the modal shows the Internet explorer message : **"To display the web page again, the web browser needs to resend... "** with the Retry, Cancel buttons. How can I avoid the double postback?

Comment: how are you binding grid?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. When refreshing a page after a modal is closed, do not use `window.location.reload()` Rather use `window.location.href=window.location.href`